# When sending concatenated sms, can I set "reference number" field of the UDH to be 16 bit instead of 8 bit?

Tags: android, sms, smsmanager

I have an Android App that sends multipart SMS using SmsManager. SMS is received using the [SMPP](https://smpp.org/) protocol.

The problem is that sometimes two different messages come from the App with the same [UDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Data_Header) (*User Data Header*). This causes issues when our [SMS gateway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) tries to merge the different parts of those messages.

I Knew from [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenated_SMS) Wikipedia article that, UDH can use a 16 bit *reference number* - instead of 8 bit - which will help reducing the probability that two different messages will have the same *reference number*.

Here is is the code that I use which adds UDH with 8 bit reference number:

```
SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
ArrayList messageParts = sms.divideMessage(msg);
...                       
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(Config.SMS_NUMBER, null, messageParts, pendingIntents, null);
```

When sending long SMS using the above code, it got received on the SMS gateway in two parts, each part contains a UDH like this:

```
05 00 03 {4A}(8-bit ref. no.) 02 01.....
05 00 03 {4A}(8-bit ref. no.) 02 02.....
```

My question is, is there a way to tell Android system to use that 16 bit *reference number*?

In other words, I would like to receive SMS on the gateway with a UDH like this:

```
06 08 04 {4A FE}(16-bit ref. no.) 02 01.....
06 08 04 {4A FE}(16-bit ref. no.) 02 02.....
```

Comment: I'm not sure if UDH IE 8 is coded for multipart (probably in C++), but if i look at java sources there is no setting for smsmanager, so probably its coded only UDH IE 0 which uses 1byte reference

Comment: thank you @Marvin,  yes I'm looking for it in the AOSP source and I didn't find any refrence for that 16-bit udh yet!

Comment: Then the only solution would be that you add your own UDH header in front of the each message fragment.